# people's morals are 'sometimes' or 'always' socially accepted values

Tags: ethics

So I disagree with the following sentence: people's morals are 'sometimes' or 'always' socially accepted values

Therefore, I would like to know which philosopher would agree with this statement and why? Which philosophical theory agrees with this statement? How so?

Comment: The statement and its rejection are both quite unclear. Can you reword in normal English?

Comment: People's morals are sometimes, but not always socially accepted values.  That is not a particularly strong or surprising statement.  Read literally, the statement in the OP is even weaker than my version - though perhaps it should be rejected for giving undue weight to the incorrect "always" option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider checking out Piaget's theory of moral development (qualitative psychology, not philosophy). In brief, he suggests that there are universal aspects of morality found in all human cultures, due to the developmental niche created by our biology (e.g., being born completely helpless and solely dependent upon your relationship with a caregiver for survival), while also accepting that "social conventions" play a role too.

It's a fascinating theory, cashed out through a plethora of examples of kids playing games together and figuring out how to interact successfully (in their natural settings, not in a lab).